# How cookies and tokens work

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm designing a web application and now I'm working on the authentication function. I read that there are two approaches: cookies and tokens. I do not really understanding how these two work.

I'm planing to use django-rest-framework-jwt if I chose tokens. Here's where I am at :

**Tokens**

The user sends his data (login and password). The application verifies that the data are correct and calculates a token and then send it back to the user. When the user make a request he includes the token in the request. The application decodes the request and we get the information about the user.

My question :

**- How do we get the token? Is it like calculating a hash code?
- How do we get the user information after we decode the token?
- How is it determined that the token is dead? 
- Can a web application that uses tokens be used through a browser**

**Cookies**

Same as tokens but cookie are sent using the HTTP header not in request body. Cookies must stored in the server side.

My question :

**- In articles I read they say that tokens have the advantage that they have life time. But cookies have that too. So what's the difference between the life time of a cookie and a token?
- How we identify the user who made the request? Do we store a dictionary (cookie, user id)?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Tokens" as you call it are identical to "Sessions" as on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/.

Similar to what you stated, Sessions calculate a hash code/id to be sent back to the user to be identified as an authenticated user etc.

To answer your questions directly:

1. Sessions and Cookies work together. Once Django generates a SessionId it is stored on user's computer through the use of a cookie while it is also recorded in django backend. Therefore, I am not sure if your question is valid. Try reading up at http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html.
2. The link above also answers this questions for you. To summarize, the SessionId sent back to the user includes an ID to identify that user as authenticated or any other property etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the difference between Cookie-based authentication (by storing sessionIds in cookies on the client) and token authentication is that an authentication token is sent in the http-header 'authentication' field. This is more flexible, since there are REST clients (native clients on phones etc.) that don't support the concept of a cookie at all.

Session Authentication is built-in in Django, session authentication is provided by Django-rest-framework.

Django-rest-framework has a built-in method of passing the token to the client, but you're welcome to implement your own devices.

Tokens are valid until they are deleted from the database. Again, you can roll your own auto-invalidation solution here.

The django-rest-framework documentation is pretty detailed about the different authentication mechanisms it supports. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication